# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.ProgressMonitor when trying to read JIRA Issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am very new to JIRA.Added dependencies for JRJC in maven. My scenario is to read Issue in my Java EE application.
I have created a simple class like
public class IssueCollector {
    public void readIssue(){

```
    final JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
    try{
        final URI jiraServerUri = new URI("http://localhost:8080//jira");
        final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri,"username", "password");
        final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
        final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("AKE-1", pm);

        System.out.println(issue);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("URI not found");
    }

}
```

}

But when i run i am getting exceptions like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/ProgressMonitor
    com.vxl.appanalytix.dataload.fromEmail.GenericEmailAttachmentDownloder.downloadEmailAttachments(GenericEmailAttachmentDownloder.java:28)
    com.vxl.appanalytix.controllers.controllerClasses.GenericEmailServiceClass.readEmailAttachments(GenericEmailServiceClass.java:13)
    com.vxl.appanalytix.controllers.GenericEmailServiceServlet.doPost(GenericEmailServiceServlet.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Am i going wrong way. Have to create web service instead of simple java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look which Version of JRJC you're using. They changed they way to reach the database so that the ProgressMonitor isn't needed anymore.
I am not sure after which it changed, but I believe that Version 1.0.0 was the last Version with the ProgressMonitor.

Comment: I changed my JRJC to 0.6 its working for ProgressMonitor. But still getting exception like java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Joiner

Comment: JRJC has a big list of dependencies, maybe you should look here to see which are missing: http://www.versioneye.com/package/com~atlassian~jira--jira-rest-java-client/version/1~0

Comment: means have to add all these dependencies to my pom.xml?

Comment: I don't know what needs to be in your pom.xml because I don't work with Maven. I am sorry I can't help you with this problem.

Comment: I am trying it from yesterday but still getting exception like  when trying to get Issue from jira that is line  final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("AKE-1", pm); as edited in above post

Comment: If you have a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, it simply means that it can't reach the class it needs, so there is a problem with the dependencies and/or pom.xml/maven, so I would check if the pom.xml is correct. What do you have written in the pom.xml?

Comment: jira is running on my localhost:8080 and tomcat too on the same. Is this is problem ? when i run as web project

Comment: Can you reach Jira? If yes, than it's not the problem you are looking for.